# Can't get piping to work in my simple linux shell

Tags: c, linux, shell

Here is the code and I am not sure what makes it not function as expected. When i type in "ls | wc" it give me this error:

```
> ls | wc
`v> wc: 'standard input': Bad file descriptor
      0       0       0
      0       0       0
```

Here is the code for the program... I think it has something to do woth how I am using the pipes?

```
void pipeTest2(Command *cmd)
{

struct c *currentProgram = cmd->pgm;

  int pipefd[2];
  pipe(pipefd); //insert error correction, if pipe fails,return

 // printf(cmd->pgm->pgmlist[i]);
 // printf(cmd->pgm->pgmlist);

  while (currentProgram != NULL)
  {

    //if fork is 0, go back to parent process.
    if (!fork())
    {
      dup2(pipefd[1], cmd->rstdout); // remap output back to parent
      if (execvp(cmd->pgm->pgmlist[0], cmd->pgm->pgmlist) < 0)
      {
        printf("Failed to execute child process.");
      }
      
    }

    // remap output from previous child to input
    dup2(pipefd[0], cmd->rstdin);
    close(pipefd[1]);

    currentProgram = currentProgram->next;
    printf(currentProgram);
  }
  return;

}
´´´
```

Comment: Your code lacks a `main` function. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What is `cmd->rstdout`? What is `cmd->rstdin`? Unless they have been initialized to `STDOUT_FILENO` and `STDIN_FILENO` (respectively) then you're not redirecting standard output or standard input.

Comment: When I see that you only ever close `pipefd[1]` I know that the code is incomplete. Further supported by the lack of information on what `struct c` and `Command` are.